# How to get stored variable value from mysql transaction

Tags: mysql, transactions

I have written a transaction for mySQL InnoDB engine.
It has an insert in a table with auto generate key, than another insert using that auto generate key which I got using `LAST_INSERT_ID()`.
Now after this second insert I have several inserts which need a foreign key for auto generated key from last table in which I have inserted.
So what I did was made a variable and used it is all of them.
Now, I need that auto generated key value to be returned in my Java program so I can use it.
How do I do it?
My transaction is fairly large so here is what I am trying to do.

```
start transaction;
insert into a(value) values(123);
insert into b(aid,value) values((select LAST_INSERT_ID()),345);
SET @KEY = ( select LAST_INSERT_ID() ) ;
insert into c(val,fk) values(1,@KEY);
insert into c(val,fk) values(2,@KEY);
insert into c(val,fk) values(3,@KEY);
.....
insert into c(val,fk) values(10,@KEY);
```

Now I need the `@KEY` variable value to be returned back in my program.
Its Java program I am using J connector for MySQL (If it matters).

Comment: Can't you just do `SELECT @KEY;` before closing the transaction?

Comment: Certainly i can but i have not tried anything like that, i have only used transactions for insert and update delete etc, actually i can't try it at the time, because i am working on a phase without having actual DB, i have schema in html and ERD. So, it will be great to have some sure solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL variables are session-scoped you can do the following anywhere you want as long as you're using the same connection :

```
SELECT @KEY;
```

For more information, the manual is your friend : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html

Comment: Which means after completion of commit i can execute extra select to get value of the variable...
Sorry for asking again, as i have said in a reply before that i am not able to test my queries at the time because of some reasons that's why i am confirming before implementing.

Comment: Thank you for the answer than. That was a fast to the point answer. (Y)

Comment: I was thinking it might be better to query the DB_schema to get last insert ID of some table, will it make any difference?
like this 
"SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = $mydb AND TABLE_NAME = $my_table;"

Comment: Nope, `LAST_INSERT_ID()` in a transaction is the way to go. Could you accept the answer if it solved your problem?